# How to navigate from a picture in WebBrowser control to a native page in Windows Phone?

Tags: image, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control to display some HTML string. and It has some < img src=""> tag in it. Now I have a requirement: when the user tap a image, I will navigate to a new native page to show the larger version and implement something like zoom features. But the WebBrowsre seems ignore the TAP event. So, how to navigate from a picture in WebBrowser control to a native page in Windows Phone?

i don't want to add a < a> link outside the < img> tag because of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974951/how-to-forbid-the-webbrowser-controls-navigating-in-windows-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect your image position in a WebBrowser control via JavaScript:

```
function fetchImagePosition()
{ 
    var rect = document.getElementByIdimageId").getBoundingClientRect(); 
        window.external.Notify(rect.left + ',' + rect.top + ',' + rect.right + ',' + rect.bottom);
}
```

Also add above script execution on your HTML is loaded:

```
window.onload = function () 
    { 
      var elem = document.getElementById('content');                                    
window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + ''); fetchLinkPosition();}
```

Enable your `WebBrowser` to execute JavaScript `IsScriptEnabled=true`. Add a handler to WebBrowser `ScriptNotify` event to catch the image position and save it to a local field:

```
  private void BrowserScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
        {
                var rectBoundaries = e.Value.Split(',').Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
                var rectHeight = rectBoundaries[3] - rectBoundaries[1];
                var rectWidth = rectBoundaries[2] - rectBoundaries[0];
                _imageRect= new Rect(rectBoundaries[0], rectBoundaries[1], rectWidth, rectHeight);

        }
```

Add `Tap` event handler to your `LayoutRoot`:

```
  private void LayoutRootTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            var point = e.GetPosition(Browser);
            if (_imageRect.Contains(point))
            {
               NavigationService.Navigate("YourPageUri");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ,but, I get a little confuse, Can I just simply fetch the "src" part of the < img> tag and pass it out ?

Comment: Sure, you can get it with  windows.onload = funcation(){return document.getElementById('image').src }

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but what confuse me is that how can you get the picture without binding the onclick method of the < img> tag?

Comment: Finally works, I don't use your code, but your solution really inspires me! Really Thanks! ScriptNotify is such a beautiful event.